# Cómo obtener la combinación N-1 de numeros con la mayor suma de un arreglo de N elementos

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

Entrada

Una línea con la cantidad N de elementos que contendrá el arreglo.

N líneas, cada una con el valor que se almacena en el arreglo.

Salida

Una línea con la mayor suma posible habiendo dejado exactamente un elemento sin comprar (puede ser cualquiera, siempre y cuando suma obtenida sea la mayor posible).

Lo resolví encontrando el valor mas pequeño del arreglo y evitando que este sea sumado al resto de elementos, como dice el ejercicio: dejando 1 sin comparar, pero quisiera saber si hay una forma más eficiente de obtener la combinación de elementos con la mayor suma dejando 1 en el arreglo, es decir, si son 5 elementos que encuentre la combinación de 4 con la mayor suma, si son 8 la combinación de 7.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int min = 0;
        int suma = 0;
        int cant = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int[] valores = new int[cant];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
            valores[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            if(min == 0)
                min = valores[i];
            min = Math.min(min, valores[i]);
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++)
            if(valores[i] != min)
                suma += valores[i];
        
        System.out.print(suma);
    }
```

Ejemplo

| Entrada | Salida | Descripción |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 27 | Se suman el 1, 2, 4 y 5 |
| 8 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |
| 8 |  |  |

Comment: y si se ingresa "0" como uno de los numeros  del array ? deberia ser tomado como el menor ?

Comment: No sería tomado en cuenta si la suma con los demas valores es menor a otras combinaciones

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas hacer 2 recorridos, sino uno, en este recorrido verificamos si el numero mínimo es mayor al nuevo ingresado, por ejemplo establecemos que tu mínimo es 999999, así que cualquier nuevo número ingresado siempre será el menor y lo establecemos el nuevo valor de la variable "min" y asi sucecivamente, luego de eso vamos sumando al total y saliendo del bucle ya a tu suma total ya le restas el numero mínimo y listo.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int min = 999999;
        int suma = 0;
        System.out.print("Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo: ");
        int cant = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int[] valores = new int[cant];

        for(int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
            
            System.out.print("Ingrese el número en la posición "+ (i+1) +": ");
            valores[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            
            //Verificamos el nuevo valor es menor al mínimo
            if(valores[i] <= min) min = valores[i];
            
            //Vamos sumando los valores
            suma += valores[i];

        }
        //Restamos a la suma total el valor mínimo
        suma -= min;

        System.out.println("La suma es: " + suma);
    }
```

*Algo que no entendí muy bien es tu tabla que publicas al final, según tú, la entrada o tamaño del arreglo es de 5 y tus mayores números son 1, 2, 4 y 5 y tu salida es 27, pero 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 = 12*

Comment: El resultado 27 no es de sumar 1, 2, 4 y 5 si no de sumar 8, 5, 6 y 8 que son el primero, el segundo, el cuarto y el quinto elemento del arreglo, o sea 1, 2, 4 y 5.

Comment: Ah entiendo, igual el código cumple con lo solicitado o hay alguna duda?

Answer (score 0):

```
int menor = valores[0];
int suma = menor;

for(int i = 1; i < valores.length; i++)
{
    suma += valores[i];

    if(valores[i] < menor)
    {
        menor = valores[i];
    }
}

suma = suma - valor;
```

Se declaran dos variables, una para guardar la sumatoria y otra para guardar el menor elemento del arreglo. Posteriormente se ejecuta un **ciclo for**, que irá comparando uno a uno los elementos del arreglo con el número almacenado en la **variable menor**, si existe un elemento en el arreglo que sea menor que el número almacenado en la **variable menor**, entonces la **variable menor** actualiza su valor con este nuevo número. Dentro del **ciclo for** además se irá haciendo la sumatoria de los elementos del arreglo, una vez fuera del **ciclo for** se resta la **variable suma** con la **variable menor**, obteniendo finalmente lo que pides.